# How would those sets look like?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

How would those sets look like?

1. $\{2(1-x) + 5\mid x \in [0, 1]\}$
2. $\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid 2(1-x) + 5 \in [0, 1]\}$

First set is set of all $2(1-x) + 5$, where $x \in [0, 1]$. How can I find the range of this set exactly, without plugging in the numbers? How can I find ranges of sets like this generally?

Second set is set of all $x$, where $2(1-x) + 5 \in [0, 1]$. This one can be solved by solving inequality $0 \leq 2(1-x) + 5 \leq 1 \implies x\in \left[3, \frac{7}{2}\right]$.

Do I get it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the $2(1-x)+5$ as a function, which we'll call $f$.

In this way, the first question is asking for the set of numbers that $f$ maps the unit interval onto; for every numbers $x \in [0,1] $ what is $f(x)$. You could plot the graph, but in general I try to break it down in stages. If I have $x \in [0,1]$ then $1-x \in [0,1]$ (why?) and so $2(1-x) \in [0,2]$ and so $2(1-x)+5 \in [5,7]$, so your answer to part 1) is the set $\{x | x \in [5,7]\}$.

You are correct for the second part. Really what this question is asking, if you've covered topics like this, is given a function and 1) given a domain, find the range and 2) given a range, find the domain. This words will help you find some other sources of information.

Comment: Another method is to simplify the function. So instead of $2(1-x)+5$ we write $7-2x$, this makes the answer to both clearer.